# Blender 2.9 - are nodes mandatory for using image textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

Back in the day, there were textures slots linked to materials

- it seems overkill to use a shader just to apply a simple unshaded image for instance
- why the option of not using nodes at all ? why a "Use Nodes" button ??? if one cannot use textures at all

thanks

Comment: It still behaves like in older versions. You can setup materials without nodes in the Material properties. Where are you having trouble ?

Comment: without nodes, how do you add a texture to the material ? there are no more textures slots like there used to be

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm trying the same. Looks like when using Nodes, it doesn't work in Unity 3D, but materials without Nodes work, at least with solid colors.